# Registering library path with ldconfig didn't work as expected

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, systemd

I'm putting together a simple debian package and have encountered a situation that I don't understand. The package has a postinst script that will install a new library configuration path into /etc/ld.so.conf.d and run ldconfig to register it.

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/acme

if [ "$(ls -A $INSTALL_PREFIX/lib)" ]; then
  echo "$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/acme.conf
  ldconfig
fi
.
.
cp -f $INSTALL_PREFIX/scripts/acme.service /etc/systemd/system/acme.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable acme.service
systemctl start acme.service
```

In the service file it has a line like:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/opt/acme/bin/acme_start.sh'
```

and then in the acme_start.sh script it runs my binary.

What i'm seeing is the binary doesn't run due to missing library dependency (verified by running ldd on it before it launched from within the acme_start.sh script) that was added as part of postinst script. If I call restart on the service it launches without issue. Now, here is the thing I don't get; if i call `ldconfig -v > /dev/null` instead of just `ldconfig` it works without issue and the service will launch as soon as it is installed.

The man page of ldconfig simple states that the -v option is for verbose. The fact that it can be manually started too after the install without any further intervention would suggest the installation worked as expected.

Is there anything obvious I am missing as to why my library path is not immediately available after a call to ldconfig but is after a call to ldconfig -v ?

UPDATE:
Running `ldconfig -v -N` so that no cache is updated also causes the same problem so I'm starting to think a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$(ls -A $INSTALL_PREFIX/lib)" ]   #1
then
  echo "INSTALL_PREFIX/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/acme.conf  #2
  ldconfig
fi
```

On line #1, you appear to be testing whether `$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib` exists. A proper way to test this is:  `if [ -d "$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib" ]; ...`

On line #2, you echo *literal* `INSTALL_PREFIX/lib` into `acme.conf`. It seems pretty clear that you intended to echo `$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib` instead.

I don't have an explanation for why `ldconfig -v` works and `ldconfig` doesn't, but fixing problem on line #2 is likely to help.

Comment: #1 Intentional as there is not always files in the lib folder (depending on configuration) but the folder will always exist so simply a check to see if files are present inside. #2 It was a typo when submitting question, fixed now thanks.